# Struggling with updating a database date by x days

Tags: php, mysql, date

I am having trouble adding 2 days to a date that is in the database. I have tried multiple ways around it but none of them are updating the database.

```
 include('CONNECT-DB.php');

 // check if the 'id' variable is set in URL, and check that it is valid
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
  {
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];

 // delete the entry
  $id = $_GET['id'];
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `offerends` FROM `data` WHERE id=$id");

$date1 = str_replace('-', '/', $result1);
$date2 = date('y-m-d',strtotime($date1 . "+2 days"));

mysql_query("UPDATE `offerends` SET `$date2` WHERE id=$id");
```

I HAVE REVISITED IT, thanks for the suggestions this is the correct code that now works for my use.

```
 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {

 $id = $_GET['id'];

  $id = $_GET['id'];
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `offerends` FROM cheapest` WHERE id=$id");

$date2 = "DATE_ADD(offerends,INTERVAL 3 DAY)";

mysql_query("UPDATE `cheapest` SET offerends=$date2  WHERE id=$id");
```

Comment: Is it really "not updating" the database? Are you sure your SQL query is syntactically correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `data` SET `offerends` = `offerends` + INTERVAL 2 DAY WHERE id=$id");
```

And especially, don't delete the entry. You can't update what isn't there. ;)

Another **important** note: I'm no programmer, but I'd bet this code isn't safe from **SQL Injections**. Don't use data directly, escape it properly. Read up about the subject!

Comment: after reading up on the code and helpful suggestions i managed to fix it to do what i wanted.

 if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id']))
 {
 // get id value
 $id = $_GET['id'];
 
 
 // delete the entry
  $id = $_GET['id'];
$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT `offerends` FROM cheapest` WHERE id=$id");

     $date2 = "DATE_ADD(offerends,INTERVAL 3 DAY)";

    mysql_query("UPDATE `cheapest` SET offerends=$date2  WHERE id=$id");

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your SQL should look like

```
UPDATE `data` SET `offerends`='$date2' WHERE id=$id
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Adjust for language specific details (like whatever those backticks are)

update: changed the link to the mysql docs. It was w3schools before. Honestly though it doesn't matter, the only reason I linked it was to show the sql syntax of

```
UPDATE [tablename] SET [columnNname] = [value] WHERE [columnname] = [value]
```

Comment: I wasn't recommending w3schools, they were the first thing I saw that had the SQL syntax of UPDATE

Comment: @rid: I know SQL, I'm not as familiar with PHP. I figured that the OP was doing something fancy I didn't know about so I left it in. The point I'm getting at is that their SQL syntax is not correct.

Comment: If it's still wrong feel free to edit it yourself or let me know what's wrong. PHP is not my specialty.

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("UPDATE `offerends` SET `$date2`= DATE_ADD(offerends,INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id='$id'");

Answer (score -1):

```
mysql_query("UPDATE `offerends` SET `$date2`= DATE_ADD(offerends,INTERVAL 2 DAY) WHERE id=$id");
```